# Oracle 12c PDB Cloning with RMAN - Aux DB connection issues

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, rman

I'm trying to run the following to duplicate a PDB using RMAN.

```
rman target  testuser/testuser@PDB01 auxiliary testuser/testuser@PDB02 as sysbackup
```

I can connect to both the target and aux PDBs remotely using sqlplus without any problems. I can connect to the target using RMAN also. But the auxiliary connection is a problem. Does anybody know why RMAN prevents a remote connection to an auxiliary database in this situation?

```
rman target testuser/testuser@PDB01 auxiliary testuser/testuser@PDB02

Recovery Manager: Release 12.1.0.2.0 - Production on Tue Jun 19 15:34:51 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

connected to target database: TESTDB1 (DBID=1985676993)
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00554: initialization of internal recovery manager package failed
RMAN-06814: cannot connect to pluggable database PDB02
If I run the commands individually I get the following ....

RMAN> connect target testuser/testuser@PDB01
connected to target database: TESTDB1 (DBID=1985676993)

RMAN> connect auxiliary testuser/testuser@PDB02

RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-06814: cannot connect to pluggable database PDB02
```

Just to prove the aux PDB02 has no issues I can use it as a the RMAN target and it works. It's just the auxiliary command that's the problem:

```
RMAN> connect target testuser/testuser@PDB02
connected to target database: TESTDB2 (DBID=958109427)
```

Any suggestions as to the possible cause of this?

Comment: does `testuser` have `SYSBACKUP` or `SYSDBA` on `PDB02` ?

Comment: Currently it has both privs granted. Tried each one individually but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ oerr rman 6814
6814, 1, "cannot connect to pluggable database %s"
// *Cause:  An error was received when connecting to database because
//          the database is a pluggable database.
// *Action: Connect to the root database and retry the command.
```

That is not how you clone a PDB.

[Duplicating PDBs](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmdupdb.htm#GUID-F8A5EEA9-F32E-4CB0-8C97-C9D0A5F942F1)

When you duplicate one or more PDBs, RMAN also duplicates the root (CDB$ROOT) and the seed database (PDB$SEED). The resulting duplicate database is a fully functional CDB that contains the root, the seed database, and the duplicated PDBs.

And this is how you do it:

[Cloning a Remote PDB or Non-CDB](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/cdb_plug.htm#GUID-D4900E43-DF38-4629-9A1F-D1C11EC8EC8F)

Example:

```
CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE pdb02 FROM pdb01@pdb01_link;
```

Comment: Thanks. I know about the create pluggable command but with Oracle 12.1 you can't do a 'hot clone' so the source PDB must be put into read only mode. I was actually trying to reproduce an RMAN duplicate of a PDB that I found here (point 5): http://db.geeksinsight.com/2013/07/25/12c-database-rman-backups-and-recovery-with-pdb/

Comment: @Franco That method connects to the root of AUXDB while it is in NOMOUNT mode and duplicates the root, seed and `PDB` of TESTDB to AUXDB. Sure, after that, you can use AUXDB to clone `PDB` to another CDB with `CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE` or unplug+plug.

Comment: So I guess just duplicating the full DB (CDB ) in the standard way (as done previously with 11g) would do exactly the same job. It's not so useful. Is it possible to clone a PDB direct from a backup?